# Can not install TeXLive 2024

Tags: installing

My system --- Win 11

using ISO file to install, want change load but get message

```
error writing "file1b2df9795a0": broken pipe
error writing "file1b2df9795a0": broken pipe
    while executing
"chan puts $::inst "checkdir""
    (procedure "update_full_path" line 6)
    invoked from within
"update_full_path"
    (procedure "texdir_setup" line 88)
    invoked from within
"texdir_setup"
    invoked from within
".tdirb invoke "
    invoked from within
".tdirb instate !disabled { .tdirb invoke } "
    invoked from within
".tdirb instate !disabled { .tdirb invoke } "
    invoked from within
".tdirb instate pressed { .tdirb state !pressed; .tdirb instate !disabled { .tdirb invoke } } "
    (command bound to event)
```

directly to install get message

[image]

How to solve it?

Comment: [Verify the ISO's checksum](https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html). If it is correct, try running the installer again; if it's incorrect, redownload the ISO and try again. If it still doesn't work, you've (probably) found a bug and should report it to [tex-live@tug.org](https://lists.tug.org/tex-live).

Comment: Confirm. I have the same problem.

Comment: That's weird, it's an old problem, I found this https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/121gpq7/installation_texlive_2023_on_windows_10_64bit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using

```
.\install-tl-windows.bat --no-gui
```

get successfully install

Comment: Didn't help, still fell over.

Comment: @sergiokapone what...? say your story